# why visualizer.getfft excites java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL

Tags: java, android, exception, fft

I think this is a very difficult question and I need a very experienced specialist, so if you can answer in advance, thank you very much :D

```
audioVisualizer = new AudioVisualizer(audioSessionId);
audioVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
try {
//  Exception ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    int a = audioVisualizer.getFft(fft);
//  Exception ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you need all Exception code :

```
java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL
2022-10-31 22:15:16.153 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  java_vm_ext.cc:570]     in call to GetPrimitiveArrayCritical
2022-10-31 22:15:16.153 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  java_vm_ext.cc:570]     from int android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.native_getFft(byte[])
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630] Runtime aborting...
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630] All threads:
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630] DALVIK THREADS (16):
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x72693e78 self=0x7490846c00
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630]   | sysTid=18560 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7491fa7ed0
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630]   | state=R schedstat=( 5524140844 782691092 6362 ) utm=512 stm=40 core=3 HZ=100
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630]   | stack=0x7fdcf36000-0x7fdcf38000 stackSize=8192KB
2022-10-31 22:15:16.595 18560-18560 m.example.musi          com.example.music                    A  runtime.cc:630]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

I googled and looked at stack overflows to no avail

Comment: For me this looks like your variable / field `fft` is null. Can you share the code where you initialize `fft`?

Comment: @ThomasKläger oh i forgot byte[] fft;

Comment: @ThomasKläger so probably the problem is in the empty fft but i just want to get the fft from the visualizer how do i initialize this line of code : int a = audioVisualizer.getFft(fft);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fft` must be an array of bytes where the FFT can be returned. If your class just has a field declaration like `byte[] fft;` then `fft` is null and `audioVisualizer.getFft()` has no place to store the captured FFT.

You must provide a byte array that is large enough (`audioVisualizer.getCaptureSize()`).

Your code must contain these lines:

```
int n = audioVisualizer.getCaptureSize();
fft = new byte[n];
int a = audioVisualizer.getFft(fft);
```